# 2D array removes its elements after exiting the loop

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Input is: hello world 
The following program should record "hello" in words[0] and "world in words[1]

```
int rowIndex= 0;
char words [100][100];
for (int x = 0 ; x < input.length(); x++)
{
  if (input[x]>='a'&&input[x]<='z' || input[x]>='A'&&input[x]<='Z')
 // This condition is to avoid recording spaces in the array
  {
      words[rowIndex][x]= input[x];
      cout << words[rowIndex][x]<<" ";
  }
  else {
    rowIndex++;
    // Once it finds a space, it records the following characters into the next index
    cout << " Index: " << rowIndex <<endl;
  }
}
```

output: 
h e l l o 
 Index: 1 
 w o r l d

```
cout <<"Index 0: "<< words[0] <<endl;
```

Output: hello

```
cout <<"Index 1: "<< words[1] <<endl;
```

Output:       " doesn't output anything" ( Why doesn't it output "world")

***************************************************** 
Why doesn't the array hold the characters in words[1] and only holds the characters in words[0] 
Note: I tried doing it with dynamic 2D array and same problem happened.

Comment: You don't reset `x` on a new word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout <<"Index 1: "<< words[1]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing `words[1][0]` that was never initialized.